# Insert array's into hash jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like ["2","3"] to user_id:["2","3"] and another array like ["4","5"] to admin_id:["4","5"] to a hashlike
 total_users:user_id:["2","3"],admin_id:["4","5"]
Like this is this possible in jquery??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Can you give a little more detail on what you currently have, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want the result as  a json like this `{"total_users":{"user_id":["2","3"],"admin_id":["4","5"]}}`?

Comment: yes @Gilsha i need like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
var userIds = ["2","3"];
var adminIds = ["4","5"];
var obj = {};
obj.total_users = {
  user_id: userIds,
  admin_id: adminIds
};
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```